# Find out the second highest in array

Tags: c

I want to find the first and second highest number in an array. I could come up with one solution, but I want to know the optimum solution to do the same. Can someone help me with some alternative solution to this?

```
int main() 
{

    int arr[10] = {0,1,2,13,4,5,9,8,11,6};
    int first = arr[0];
    int second = arr[0];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(first < arr[i])
        {
            second = first;
            first = arr[i];
        }
        else if(second < arr[i])
        {
            second = arr[i];
        }

    }

    printf("First = %d\n", first);
    printf("Second = %d\n", second);


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> First = 13
> Second = 11
> ```

Comment: check this link it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628718/find-the-2nd-largest-element-in-an-array-with-minimum-of-comparisom

Comment: Looks good for me. It's O(N) (one `for` loop iterating over array elements) for a task that simply cannot do better.

Comment: Is it question asked you in any programming contest?

Comment: It's working but I want to know other better way to do the same?

Comment: Sort the array in ascending order and grab the last two elements.

Comment: @bstar55 In C, and probably for a programming assignment .. Yet that is how I would do it in general in a language like C# (or really any language with a trivial/standard sort expression).

Comment: @bstar55: That would be unnecessarily slow.

Comment: if elements of array are random them then you cant do better then O(n)

Comment: @kapilddit Look here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/to-find-smallest-and-second-smallest-element-in-an-array/

Comment: Haha, the OP said "some alternative solution", which opens the door for unnecessarily slow options.  I think the posted code looks great as is.

Comment: (on sidenote, the compilers these days are crazily good, both gcc and clang optimized this code to just `printf` statements with hardcoded results)

Comment: @xfix Ah, yeah. Missed the `else` whoops :|

Comment: You could start from `i = 1` since the iteration with `i == 0` never does anything

Comment: One of the best approaches to this is to sort the array using quick sort or merge sort, in an ascending order. Get the result from the sorted array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a problem in your code. Assuming that input is `[3, 2, 1]`, the program will work like this.

1. Set `first` and `second` as 3.
2. Iterate through elements noticing that nothing is larger than 3.
3. Claim that 3 is the second number.

To fix this, you can do something like this.

```
if (arr[0] < arr[1]) {
    second = arr[0];
    first = arr[1];
}
else {
    second = arr[1];
    first = arr[0];
}

for (i = 2; i < elems; i++) {
    /* Your code */
}
```

Also, your program doesn't work well when `NaN` is involved in first position. This probably doesn't really matter (currently this handles integers, not double floating point numbers), but this may be still relevant for you, as it would require some special code to handle `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     int first = arr[0];
>     int second = arr[0];
>     int i;
>
>     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
> ```

As pointed out [elsewhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/57781/71574), your code is buggy in the face of inputs where the first element is the correct `first`.  Then `second` will never get set properly.  The simplest fix is to change two of these four lines as so

```
    int first = arr[0];
    int second = arr[1];
    int i;

    /* if first and second are out of order, the i = 1 iteration will fix it */
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
```

Now if `arr[0]` is greater than or equal to `arr[1]`, then `first` and `second` are already correct for the first two elements.  Nothing will happen because `first` and `second` are not less than `arr[1]`.

If `arr[0]` is less than `arr[1]`, then the check will return true for `first < arr[i]` because `first` is `arr[0]` and `arr[i]` is `arr[1]`.  So `second` will be set to `first` (`arr[0]`) and first will be set to `arr[1]`, the correct ordering.

I find this a better solution than starting `i` at 2 and setting `first` and `second` correctly before starting the loop, as it removes the unique check.

I changed `10` to `length` as the 10 can change.  I'd rather do that change earlier, where the array is set.  Then I'm not having to find everywhere the array is used to change the length.

Comment: But there's a problem here: suppose you have an array {10, 9, 8, 7}. Then at the start `first = 10` and `second = 9`. Then you start from 10 and check `if (10>first) {second=first; first=10;} else if (10>second) {second=10;}`. It's the `else if` block where it breaks. If the maximum number is the first, then it is going to be assigned to `second`. So one must start from `i = 2`, while you say "I find this a better solution than starting i at 2".

Comment: You must either check `else if (10!=first && 10>second) {second = 10;}` or start the cycle from `i=1` (if i start from 0, meaning you iterate starting from the second element).

Comment: If you have `{10, 9, 8, 7}`, then `a[i]` is `a[1]` or `9`.  So you would check `if (9 > 10)` and `else if (9 > 9)`.  Both of those are false.  More generally, as I said, "Nothing will happen because `first` and `second` are not less than `arr[1]`."  Your code acts as if it starts at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you can really achieve the first and second largest ones in the posted code, that will be with best performance. And don’t expect the optimum  solution.

Unfortunately, your code is incomplete to achieve that. The largest(first) is correct. But the second is not that easy. Suppose `arr[10] = {20,1,2,13,4,5,9,8,11,6}`, then 1st and 2nd will never be modified. You will see the flaw now.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Problem comes when highest number is placed at first position in array mean at arr[0]. Then above mentioned code will not work as expected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sorting algorithm and can get first and second highest element in array.
Using bubble sort.

```
int temp=0;
int n=10;
   for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
         for(j=0;j< n-1;j++)
         if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
               {
               temp=arr[j];
               arr[j]=arr[j+1];
               arr[j+1]=temp;
               }
    }
printf("First = %d\n", arr[9]);
printf("Second = %d\n", arr[8]);
```

Comment: Sorting is overkill just to get highest two numbers. A simple `O(N)` solution exists.

Comment: His method seems more optimal... O(n) vs O(n^2)...

Comment: @BlueMoon I have just given altenate solution to his problem.User may choose best algo depending on time complexity.Bubble sort would be fast if data is small and if it is sorted then would improve performance too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code requires approx. 2n comparisons.

If you implemented the following method you can do it in approx n+log n comparisons.

Organize a 'elimination style tournament' between the numbers. For example you have 4 numbers,

```
   Greatest
   /     \
  W1     W2
 / \    /  \
X   X   X   X
```

Where the X's are your numbers , then you require n-1 comparisons to find the greatest. Then the second greatest could have only been beaten by the greatest number. So it is one of the log n numbers that greatest has beaten. Therefore you need log n comparisons to find second greatest, overall, approx n+log n instead of approx 2n.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a ;
int b ;
if (array[0] < array[1]) {b = array[0];a = array[1];}
                    else {b = array[1];a = array[0];}
 for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) 
  { if (array[i] > a) 
    { b = a;a = array[i];}
     else if (array[i] >= b&&i!=array.length-1)
      b = array[i];
  }
System.out.println("Second highest:"+b);
```

This works essentially on anything including as given above reverse orders, and also negatives.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.